# pytest-cov does not cover all lines when using sqlalchemy async session

Tags: sqlalchemy, pytest-cov

I have a simple fastapi script that executes a query to postgresql using sqlalchemy async session, however pytest-cov does not seem to mark lines under `session.get` although I'm pretty sure it is executed. If I change `get_session` to the commented version (synchronous session), pytest-cov works just fine.

`app/main.py`

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends

import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker, Session


# Orm
Base = declarative_base()


class TableOrm(Base):
    __tablename__ = "mytable"

    key = sa.Column(sa.String(length=16), primary_key=True)
    value = sa.Column(sa.Float(), nullable=False)


# Dependencies
async def get_session():
    database_uri = (
        "postgresql+asyncpg://***@localhost:5432/playground"
    )
    engine = create_async_engine(database_uri)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine, class_=AsyncSession)

    async with Session() as session:
        yield session


# def get_session():
#     database_uri = "postgresql://***@localhost:5432/playground"
#     engine = create_engine(database_uri)

#     with Session(bind=engine) as session:
#         yield session


# App
app = FastAPI()


@app.get(path="/example")
async def function(key: str, session=Depends(get_session)):
    entity = await session.get(TableOrm, key)

    if entity:
        return {"key": entity.key, "value": entity.value}
    return {"key": key, "value": -1}
```

`app/tests/test_example.py`

```py
from httpx import AsyncClient
from app.main import app


async def test_entity_found():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
        params = {"key": "keyexist"}
        response = await client.get("/example", params=params)

        assert response.status_code == 200

        out = response.json()
        assert out["value"] == 15.0


async def test_entity_not_found():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as client:
        params = {"key": "keynotexist"}
        response = await client.get("/example", params=params)

        assert response.status_code == 200

        out = response.json()
        assert out["value"] == -1
```

This is the output of `pytest --asyncio-mode=auto --cov=app --cov-report=term-missing app/tests/`

```
app/tests/test_example.py ..                                                                                                                                                                       [100%]

---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.9.12-final-0 ----------
Name                        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------
app/__init__.py                 0      0   100%
app/main.py                    25      3    88%   50-52
app/tests/__init__.py           0      0   100%
app/tests/test_example.py      16      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                          41      3    93%
```

This is the library version I'm using

```
asyncpg                   0.27.0
coverage                  6.5.0
psycopg2                  2.9.5
pytest                    7.2.0
pytest-asyncio            0.20.1
pytest-cov                4.0.0
SQLAlchemy                1.4.38
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3557) and [here](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/1082), the reason for this issue is that FastAPI uses threads and SQLAlchemy uses greenlet to support async behavior, and coverage has problems keeping track of both.
The solution is to add this to your `.coveragerc` file:

```
[coverage:run]
concurrency =
  greenlet
  thread
```